# Nestjs applyDecorators for multiple decorators

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'd like to create custom decorator with `applyDecorators` imported from `@nestjs/common`

```
...

applyDecorators(
  @Field(),
  @MinLength(2)
)

...
```

But I got typescript lint errors. How can I create a custom decorator which wraps several decorators?

https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators

```
"class-validator": "^0.11.0"
"@nestjs/common": "^7.0.9"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a custom decorator method using `applyDecorators` method.

`applyDecorators` method accepts `PropertyDecorator` as arguments. so please make sure to convert them as `PropertyDecorator`.

```
export const NameField = (options?: FieldOptions) =>
  applyDecorators(
    Field() as PropertyDecorator, // convert to PropertyDecorator
    MinLength(2) as PropertyDecorator // convert to PropertyDecorator
  )
)
```

Comment: This not works. Doesn't trigger any error, but the param doesn't appear on Swagger doc